# How to add variable names to the JMeter CSV output file?

Tags: variables, csv, logging, jmeter

I'm using JMeter for performance testing and generate an CSV file for data analysis.

How should I add JMeter Variable names to the CSV output? It seems that only pre-defined columns can be added (see screenshot).

This is my log-file:

```
14/03/2014,Login,OK,982
14/03/2014,Search,OK,2182
14/03/2014,Login,OK,3982
```

I would like to add a column with the ${username} to generate something like:

```
14/03/2014,Login,OK,982,user1
14/03/2014,Search,OK,2182,user7
14/03/2014,Login,OK,3982,user9
```

[image: JMeter Results to output CSV file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass `sample_variables` property, for example as command-line parameter  `-Jsample_variables=username,some_other_var`

Also see FlexibleFileWriter plugin if you need custom formatting http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=FlexibleFileWriter