# JMeter - How can I capture values from Response data and add them in the same CSV results file that is used to generate HTML reports

Tags: jmeter

I need to capture some values from Response data and add them to the same CSV file which is used to generate HTML reports (not to a separate CSV file). The reason I want to do this is to filter the Response times by any value I capture, in this case LOBs or GroupIDs (last 2 columns). In the picture, column A thru P are from JMeter generated results, but I want to add column Q and R also with captured values.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3LRo.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add variable names to the JMeter CSV output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400660/how-to-add-variable-names-to-the-jmeter-csv-output-file)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract `LOBs` and `GroupIDs`, make sure to use **exactly** the same variable reference name:

   [image]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=LOBs,GroupIDs
   ```
3. That's it, next time you start JMeter you will see 2 extra columns added to the .jtl results file containing variable values for each Sample Result.

If you don't want to make the change permanent instead of adding the above line to the *user.properties* file you can pass it via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=LOBs,GroupIDs -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

References:

- [Sample Variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)